# Java simple assignment

Tags: java

I am trying to solve a simple assignment from a course I have enrolled in, but it's not working for some reason.

**Assignment says**: "*A year is a leap year if it is divisible by 4. But if the year is divisible by 100, it is a leap year only when it is also divisible by 400.
Create a program that checks whether the given year is a leap year.*"

**When I run the code** I get the message: "*With input 1604 you should print "The year is a leap year", but you printed "Type a year: The year is not a leap year."* "

This is my code:

```
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Type a year: ");
    int year = Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine());

    if((year % 4 == 0) && (year % 100 == 0 && year % 400 == 0)) {
        System.out.println("The year is a leap year.");
    }else {
        System.out.println("The year is not a leap year.");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Use a debugger to see the values of `year % 4`, `year % 100` and `year % 400`.

Comment: Just *think* about what happens for the input 4, is it a leap year, what does the code output? Dont start with weird cases like 1604, start with the simple ones and check why even they already fail.

Comment: Are you sure that your program is supposed to print `"Type a year: "`?

Comment: Learn how to search properly.  This link was the first hit from Google.

Comment: Thank you all for answering. I am a total beginner and just joined SO, so sorry for duplicated post. Of course, I found what I was looking for in previous question that was posted before.

Comment: you can short it also:  
private static Boolean isLeapYear(int year) {
  return year % 4 == 0 ? (year % 100 == 0 ? ( year % 400 == 0 ? true : false) : true) : false ;
 }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if((year % 4 == 0) && (year % 100 == 0 && year % 400 == 0)` uses `&&` it should be `||`. It should be `if((year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0) || (year % 400 == 0)`

1604 is divisible by 4 but since you use `&&`, it also checks if its divisible by 100 and 400 which it isn't.

Comment: where should it be `||`?

Comment: edited my statement.

Comment: `(year % 100 == 0 && year % 400 == 0)` is redundant, because `year % 100 == 0` is true when `year % 400 == 0`. And this overall condition will say that 1900 is a leap year, which it is not. So, this is incorrect.

Comment: Yea you're right, it should be moved to the first condition  `(year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0)`

Comment: Thank you guys, I managed to solve the problem.